# Array, sharing between components: Angular

Tags: angular

I'm storing some values in an array domain:Domain[], if I wanted to transfer the array from a parent's component to a child's component by using the child's selector inside of my parents html file then declaring the decorator @Input() domain: Domain[]; in my child's component to get the contents inside the array should I be able to use domain.id if I wanted inside a function in my child's component? I'm just having a  hard time grasping this concept.

This is the stackblitz file: https://stackblitz.com/github/pennyfea/Project3-HCI

This is my parent's component where I'm storing the initial data in the array. Then I would try to pass it over to the child's component using the child's selector inside of the parent's html file. Something I've seen on a number of other questions and tutorials.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ImageService } from './shared/image.service';
import { DomainService } from '../domain.service';
import { GraphService } from '../graph.service';
import { LibraryService } from '../library.service';
import { Domain } from '../library';
import { Library } from '../library';
import { map,mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-metric-details',
  templateUrl: './metric-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metric-details.component.css']
})
export class MetricDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  visibleImages: any[] = [];
  activeId = 0;
  domain: Domain[];

  constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private domainService: DomainService, private libraryService:LibraryService, private graphService:GraphService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute,  private router: Router) {
    this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();

}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.subscribe(params => { {this.activeId = +params['id'];
      console.log(this.activeId); //log the entire params object
    // console.log(params['id']) //log the value of id
    // const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // console.log(id);
      console.log(this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId));
      // this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId).subscribe(domain =>this.domain = domain;console.log("Added",this.domain);});
      this.domainService.getDomain(this.activeId).subscribe(domain => {this.domain = domain; console.log(this.domain);})
    }
  }
```

```html
<h2>Visualized Software Metrics</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="domain?.catergory">Domain: {{ domain.catergory | uppercase }}</h2>
<h2 *ngIf="library?.name">Library: {{ library.name | uppercase }}</h2>
<div class = "row">
  <ul id = "thumbnailslist">
    <li *ngFor="let image  of visibleImages ">
      <a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id]">
        <img src = "{{image.url}}" class = "tn">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<app-metric-view [domain] = "domain"></app-metric-view>
```

This is my child's component where I want to get the information from my parent's component using the input decorator, then using the information from the array say the domain.id inside a function.

```js
<div *ngIf="image">
  <h2>{{ image.catergory | uppercase }}</h2>
<div>

  <div *ngIf = "domain.id === 1" class ="row" >
    <button (click)="prev()" class="previous round">&#8249;</button>
      <div  [ngStyle] = "{'background-image': 'url('+ testing.url +')'}" class ="img-container">
      </div>
    <button (click)="next()" class="next round">&#8250;</button>
  </div>


  <!-- <div class ="row" >
      <button (click)="prev()" class="previous round">&#8249;</button>
      <div  [ngStyle] = "{'background-image': 'url('+ testing.url +')'}" class ="img-container">
      </div>
      <button (click)="next()" class="next round">&#8250;</button>
  </div>

</div> -->

<div class = "tab-rating">
  <ngbd-rating-template></ngbd-rating-template>
  <ngbd-tabset-basic></ngbd-tabset-basic>
</div>



<!-- <div *ngIf="domain.id != 1" class ="row" >
    <button (click)="prev()" class="previous round">&#8249;</button>
    <div  [ngStyle] = "{'background-image': 'url('+ testing.url +')'}" class ="img-container">
    </div>
    <button (click)="next()" class="next round">&#8250;</button>
</div> -->
```

```html
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { ImageService } from '../metric-details/shared/image.service';
import { LibraryService } from '../library.service';
import { Library } from '../library';
import { Domain } from '../library';
import { GraphService } from '../graph.service';
import { DomainService } from '../domain.service';
import { map,mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-metric-view',
  templateUrl: './metric-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./metric-view.component.css']
})
export class MetricViewComponent implements OnInit {
image: any;
testing: any;
visibleImages: any[] = [];

@Input() domain: Domain[];


  constructor(private imageService: ImageService, private libraryService:LibraryService, private domainService: DomainService, private graphService:GraphService, private location: Location, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();
   }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.testing =  this.graphService.getTestingGraphs(domain.id);
    console.log(this.testing);
    this.image = this.imageService.getImage(domain.id);
    console.log(this.image);

}

  next() {
    // const next = this.activeId + 1 >= this.image.length - 1  ? this.graph.length - 1 : this.activeId + 1;
    const next = this.activeId + 1 >= 9  ? 1 : this.activeId + 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/image/' + next]);
  }

  prev() {
    const prev = this.activeId - 1 < 1 ? 9 : this.activeId - 1;
    this.router.navigate(['/image/' + prev]);
  }

}
```

Comment: So, is there a problem? Is this not working? Or, are you looking for a code review?

Comment: It does not work, it tells me domain is not defined in my parent's html file as well as child's component.ts file

Comment: @DiabolicWords domain undefined

Comment: @R.Richards no there is an actual problem. Not a code review. It gives me an error of domain undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hecme9?file=src/app/metric-view/metric-view.component.ts).
The error is when you make click on the **metric-view component**, you are no longer using nested components communication but using routing to pass that domain to that component.

```
constructor(
    private imageService: ImageService, 
    private libraryService:LibraryService, 
    private domainService: DomainService, 
    private graphService:GraphService, 
    private location: Location, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
      this.route.params.subscribe((domain: Domain) => {
          this.domain = domain;
      });
      this.visibleImages = this.imageService.getImages();
   }
```

When you click on that image, that component no get render thanks to this line **metric-details.component.html** (by the way, you comment it out)

```
<app-metric-view [domain] = "domain"></app-metric-view>
```

It is getting render thanks to the magic of Angular rounting:

```
<a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id]">
  <img src = "{{image.url}}" class = "tn">
</a>
```

and since `image.id` has the data you need to for things to work propertly, you get access to that info, in this way:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((domain: Domain) => {
  this.domain = domain;
});
```

Comment: Could you explain more for me. Not quite sure what's the issue. Because I still get the same domain is not defined error.

Comment: Can we talk in a chat?

Comment: Ok that make sense, I don't really just want to get the id number alone. I want to keep track of the catergory/domain that was chosen. So for example in the domain array i should be able to pass to the child component. "{id: 1, catergory: "testing"}"

Comment: Thats why i'm using the input decorator, I'm not really concerned with the image.id

Comment: but you can add it to the routerLink, <a [routerLink] = "['/image', image.id, domain]">
        <img src = "{{image.url}}" class = "tn">
      </a>

Comment: Ok that’s perfect then how would use that domain.name and I’d number to reference to a function?

Comment: Actually nvm, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bunch of code there but practice is not to use constructor to do things, rather use OnInit to call service and get images.

Answer (score 0):

The stackblitz sample project had two syntax problems.  In `app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts` your class declaration was never terminated (perhaps confusing the closing brace for `ngOnInit` with the closing brace for the class).  Fix that up:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  domain = DOMAIN;
  constructor(
    private location: Location, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { } 
}
```

And then clean up similar syntax issues within `metric-details.component.ts`.  Here's a [version of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vli4rr) for reference with those errors cleaned up.  If it still differs from what you were trying to accomplish, having a working sample will better direct the conversation with those who are willing to help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure where the syntax errors are but I did readjust the code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vli4rr